# CakePHP 4 JWT integration: Token 'Signature verification failed'

Tags: api, cakephp, jwt, authorization

I have tried to implement JWT based authentication in my CakePHP 4 application. Token is successfully generated and I have verified it on jwt.io as well. But while doing request for the route which should validate token it's giving following error "Authentication is required to continue".

While investigation the issue I the dd($this->Authentication); in the Controller's initialize function I see following reason In the object. "Signature verification failed" response.

Any help in this case?

Thanks,

Following is my code

routes.php

web related routes....

here are API related routes.

```
$routes->prefix('api', ['path' => '/api'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions(['json']);
    // $routes->resources('register');
    $routes->post('/user/add', ['controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'add']);
    $routes->post('/user/login', ['controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->post('/user/index', ['controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->get('/user/logout', ['controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'logout']);

    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

src/Application.php code

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (https://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (https://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link      https://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since     3.3.0
 * @license   https://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

namespace App;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Core\ContainerInterface;
use Cake\Core\Exception\MissingPluginException;
use Cake\Datasource\FactoryLocator;
use Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\BaseApplication;
use Cake\Http\Middleware\BodyParserMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;
use Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue;
use Cake\ORM\Locator\TableLocator;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware;
use Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware;

use Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface;
use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface;
use Authentication\Identifier\IdentifierInterface;
use Authentication\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware;
// use Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

/**
 * Application setup class.
 *
 * This defines the bootstrapping logic and middleware layers you
 * want to use in your application.
 */
class Application extends BaseApplication implements AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Load all the application configuration and bootstrap logic.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function bootstrap(): void
    {

        $this->addPlugin('Migrations');

        // Call parent to load bootstrap from files.
        parent::bootstrap();

        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
            $this->bootstrapCli();
        } else {
            FactoryLocator::add(
                'Table',
                (new TableLocator())->allowFallbackClass(false)
            );
        }

        /*
         * Only try to load DebugKit in development mode
         * Debug Kit should not be installed on a production system
         */
        if (\Cake\Core\Configure::read('debug')) {
            $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
        }

        $this->addPlugin('Authentication');

        // Load more plugins here
    }

    /**
     * Setup the middleware queue your application will use.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue The middleware queue to setup.
     * @return \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue The updated middleware queue.
     */
    public function middleware(MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue): MiddlewareQueue
    {
        $csrf = new CsrfProtectionMiddleware(['httponly' => true]);

        // Token check will be skipped when callback returns `true`.
        $csrf->skipCheckCallback(function ($request) {
            // Skip token check for API URLs.
            // return $request->getPath() == '/dwolla_webhook';
            return $request->getPath() == '/dwolla_webhook' || $request->getParam('prefix') == 'Api';
        });
        $middlewareQueue
            // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
            // and make an error page/response
            ->add(new ErrorHandlerMiddleware(\Cake\Core\Configure::read('Error')))

            // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
            ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
                'cacheTime' => \Cake\Core\Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime'),
            ]))


            // ->add(function (
            // \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request,
            // \Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface $handler
            // ) {
            //     try {
            //         // continue with the next middleware
            //         return $handler->handle($request);
            //     } catch (\Cake\Http\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException $exception) {

            //         // handle the catched exception
            //         $response = new \Cake\Http\Response();

            //         return $response->withStringBody('Oh noes, CSRF error!');
            //     }
            // })

            // Add routing middleware.
            // If you have a large number of routes connected, turning on routes
            // caching in production could improve performance. For that when
            // creating the middleware instance specify the cache config name by
            // using it's second constructor argument:
            // `new RoutingMiddleware($this, '_cake_routes_')`
            ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this))

            // Parse various types of encoded request bodies so that they are
            // available as array through $request->getData()
            // https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#body-parser-middleware
            ->add(new BodyParserMiddleware())

            // Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Protection Middleware
            // https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/middleware.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware
            // ->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
            //     'httponly' => true,
            // ]));
            ->add($csrf)
            ->add(new AuthenticationMiddleware($this));

        return $middlewareQueue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a service provider instance.
     *
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request Request
     * @return \Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface
     */
    public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
    {
        $service = new AuthenticationService();

        // Load identifiers
        $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
            'fields'   => [
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password',
            ],
            // 'algorithm' => 'HS256',
            'resolver' => [
                'className' => 'Authentication.Orm',
                // 'finder'    => 'active',
                'userModel' => 'User',
            ],
            
        ]);

        // Load the authenticators
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password',
            ],
            'returnPayload' => false,
            // 'loginUrl' => '/users/token.json'
        ]);

        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Jwt', [
            'secretKey' => file_get_contents(CONFIG . '/jwt.pem'),
            'header' => 'Authorization',
            // 'queryParam' => 'token',
            'tokenPrefix' => 'Bearer',
            'algorithm' => 'HS256',
            'returnPayload' => false,
        ]);

        $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.JwtSubject', [
            // 'tokenField' => 'id',
            // 'dataField' => 'id',
            'algorithm' => 'HS256',
        ]);

        // Configure the service. (see below for more details)
        return $service;

    }

    /**
     * Register application container services.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Core\ContainerInterface $container The Container to update.
     * @return void
     * @link https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/dependency-injection.html#dependency-injection
     */
    public function services(ContainerInterface $container): void
    {
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrapping for CLI application.
     *
     * That is when running commands.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function bootstrapCli(): void
    {
        try {
            $this->addPlugin('Bake');
        } catch (MissingPluginException $e) {
            // Do not halt if the plugin is missing
        }

        $this->addPlugin('Migrations');

        // Load more plugins here
    }
}
```

APIController code

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\EventInterface;

class ApiController extends Controller
{

    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');
    }

    private function setCorsHeaders()
    {
        $this->response = $this->response->cors($this->request)
            ->allowOrigin(['*'])
            ->allowMethods(['*'])
            ->allowHeaders(['x-xsrf-token', 'Origin', 'Content-Type', 'X-Auth-Token', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization', 'HTTP_Authorization', 'X-Requested-With'])
            ->allowCredentials(['true'])
            ->exposeHeaders(['Link'])
            ->maxAge(300)
            ->build();
    }

    public function beforeRender(EventInterface $event)
    {
        // .......
        $this->setCorsHeaders();
    }
    public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
    {
        // ......
        if ($this->request->is('OPTIONS')) {
            $this->setCorsHeaders();
            return $this->response;
        }
    }

}
```

UserController code

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Api;

use Cake\View\JsonView;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use App\Controller\ApiController;
use Lib\PpState\PpState;

class UserController extends ApiController
{

    // public function viewClasses(): array
    // {
    //     return [JsonView::class];
    // }

    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadModel('User');
        // var_dump(debug_backtrace());
        // dd($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);
        dd($this->Authentication);
        $this->Authentication->allowUnauthenticated(['login', 'add']);
        // dd('hhesssssheh');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // dd('ashsh');
        $this->Authentication->logout();
        // dd($this->Authentication->getResult());
        // dd($this->Authentication);
        $json = [
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'welcome',
        ];
        $this->set(compact('json'));
        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', 'json');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        // JWT::destroy();
        // $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($key, 'HS256'));
        // dd($decoded);
        // dd($this->request);
        //
        // $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        // dd($result);
        // $json = ['route' => 'logout'];
        // if ($result->isValid()) {
        //     $this->Authentication->logout();
        //     // $this->set('user', [
        //     //     'message' => 'You are successfully logout'
        //     // ]);
        //     $json = ['message' => 'You are successfully logout'];
        // }
        $json = [
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'You are successfully logout',
        ];
        $this->set(compact('json'));
        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', 'json');
        // $this->viewBuilder->setOption('serialize', 'user');

        // $this->set(compact('json'));
        // $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', 'json');

        // If the user is logged in send them away.
        // if ($result->isValid()) {
        //     $target = $this->Authentication->getLoginRedirect() ?? '/home';
        //     return $this->redirect($target);
        // }
        // if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //     $this->Flash->error('Invalid username or password');
        // }
    }

    public function add()
    {
        if ($this->User->emailInUse($this->request->getData('username'))) {
            $json = [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'User email already exists, Please choose different email',
            ];
        } else {
            $user = $this->User->newEntity($this->request->getData());
            $newUser = $this->User->save($user);
            if (!empty($newUser->id)) {
                $privateKey = file_get_contents(CONFIG . '/jwt.key');
                $payload = [
                    'iss' => 'myapp',
                    'sub' => $newUser->id,
                    'iat' => time(),
                    'exp' => time() + 300,
                ];
                if (!in_array($this->request->getData('st'), PpState::getActiveStateAbbreviations())) {
                    $json = [
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => 'Oh, bother! Poppins Payroll does not yet operate in your state. We’ve made note of your location, so we know where we’re needed. We look forward to being able to serve you soon.',
                    ];
                } else {
                    $json = [
                        'success' => true,
                        'token' => JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'HS256'),
                    ];
                }
            } else {
                $json = [
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Issue in user registration',
                ];
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('json'));
        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', 'json');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $privateKey = file_get_contents(CONFIG . '/jwt.key');
            $user = $result->getData();
            $payload = [
                'iss' => 'myapp',
                'sub' => $user->id,
                'iat' => time(),
                'exp' => time() + 60,
            ];
            $json = [
                'success' => true,
                'token' => JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'HS256'),
            ];
        } else {
            $this->response = $this->response->withStatus(401);
            $json = [];
        }
        $this->set(compact('json'));
        $this->viewBuilder()->setOption('serialize', 'json');
    }
}
```

Postman API calls

[image]

I am looking for CakePHP 4 Authorization issue to solve while implementing JWT token bases APIs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order in which you load the authenticator in your Application.php.

You should load your Jwt first and then the Form authenticator.

```php
$service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Jwt', [
    'secretKey' => Security::getSalt(),
    'returnPayload' => false
]);

$service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
    'fields' => $fields,
    'loginUrl' => '/users/login'
]);
```